# Display page number on chapter title page

Tags: page-numbering, report

How do I display page number on all the pages on my document. The page number does not appear on chapter title pages or on pages which indicate parts like Part I. I am using `report` document class.

My code looks like this ..

```
\documentclass[12pt, parskip=full]{report}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in,]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}   
\input{abstr}
\clearpage

\input{ack}
\clearpage

\input{abbrev}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\part{Introduction}
\input{intro}
```

The Introduction page (the one due to the `\part{Introduction}`)looks like this ..
[image]

I would want to display the page number on this page. The same this goes for the pages where a particular chapter begins.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: By default part start pages use `\thispagestyle{empty}`. So you have to patch the `\part` command. Chapters use `plain` style. Also, your document is only a fragment, having `\input` statements for files we can't access.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, please ? What should I be doing ?

Comment: `\usepackage{xpatch}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \xpatchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
}` before `\begin{document}` should solve your part page numbering problem. The chapter page numbers are there -- if not, you're doing something that is obscured from us

Comment: Or use `\makeatletter\let\ps@empty\ps@plain\makeatother`, in the preamble

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, but it just doesn't seem to work !

Comment: You're hiding too much of your document. We can only guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me ! Is there I've tried to include all the preamble and where the document generally starts. Is there anything else that would help you diagnose my situation any better ?

Comment: Try to comment the `\input` statements one after another until your problem vanishes, the last one that was commented seems to be culprit. For use, it would be really easier, if we would have the minimal document, that still has this issue.

Comment: What distribution of LaTeX/TeX are you using, OS? I just compile your code and added the \end{document} command at the end and it compiles perfectly with page numbering in PART and CHAPTER pages

Comment: Is there any news here?